# filtering an array of objects from API returning empty array

Tags: javascript, filtering

I have an array of objects that I got from the NPS.gov site. I am trying to filter them by just one category. here is the sample data that I was able to store in the nationalParkAlerts array:

```
0: {title: "Quincy Center T Station Closed Weekends August 25 to October 21", id: "1BF329E4-1DD8-B71B-0BAF135EA5D8A333", description: "The Quincy Center Subway ("T") Station will be clo…ink. Please call 617-770-1175 with any questions.", category: "Park Closure", url: "https://www.mbta.com/wollaston", …}
1: {title: "Strong Winds and Hazard Trees", id: "14782F36-1DD8-B71B-0BCA86558413B16E", description: "Because of recent fires and forest die-back, some …l away from stands of dead or fire damaged trees.", category: "Caution", url: "", …}
2: {title: "Precautions for Zika Virus", id: "0A624DA1-1DD8-B71B-0B010C099120ED6E", description: "There are no areas of ongoing, active transmission…ved shirts and long pants during your park visit.", category: "Information", url: "https://www.nps.gov/articles/zika-virus.htm", …}
```

and here is the code I am using:

```
const endpoint = 'https://api.nps.gov/api/v1/alerts?limit=50&api_key=' + apikey;
const nationalParkAlerts = [];

fetch(endpoint + apikey).then(function (response) {
  response.json().then(function (alertsResponse) {
    nationalParkAlerts.push(...alertsResponse.data);
  });
  filterAlerts();
});

// console.log(nationalParkAlerts);

function filterAlerts() {
  console.log(nationalParkAlerts);

  const filteredAlerts = nationalParkAlerts.filter(function (onlyAlerts) {
    return onlyAlerts.category === "Caution";
  });
  console.log("alerts that have been filtered");
  console.log(filteredAlerts);
}
```

For some reason it keeps giving me an empty array. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Since `json()` is async, you need to put `filterAlerts()` inside its `then()` so it only runs after the json is parsed.

Comment: First, check you are setting the **apiKey** two times, it is already on the variable **endpoint**, and then you call `fetch(endpoint + apikey)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your filterAlerts function invokes before actual data is loading. Try placing it inside of your `then` callback

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you add the api key to the uri when defining `endpoint` and when making the request. Also you call `filterAlerts()` outside of the `.then` of `response.json` so it probably get executed before the json is parsed.

```
fetch(endpoint) // Removed the + apiKey that already happend
.then(function (response) {
    response.json().then(function (alertsResponse) {
        nationalParkAlerts.push(...alertsResponse.data);
        filterAlerts(); // Call it here when the json is parsed
    });
    // filterAlerts(); this gets called before the .then of response.json
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display where you have the commented console.log, it might not show because it's async. Try using it in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `filterAlerts()` is being executed before your `nationalParkAlerts` array is populated, since the `json()` function of the Fetch API works asynchronously.

On top of that, you're adding the API key to your URL twice.

Try

```
fetch(endpoint)
.then(function (response) {
    response.json().then(function (alertsResponse) {
        nationalParkAlerts.push(...alertsResponse.data);
        filterAlerts();
    });

});
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the alerts in the `.then` callback because Fetch API runs asynchronously. Your filter function is most likely running before the JSON is parsed. Also, your endpoint variable already contains the apikey so you don't need to concatenate it again when fetching.

```
fetch(endpoint).then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(function(alertsResponse) {
        nationalParkAlerts.push(...alertsResponse.data);
        filterAlerts();
     });
});
```